# |ab|=lcm(|a|,|b|) in an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, least-common-multiple

Assume in an abelian group $G$ that $\langle b\rangle\cap \langle a\rangle=e$, then the order of $(ab)$ is the lcm of the orders of $a$ and $b$.  Essentially, $|ab|=\operatorname{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$.

So far I have the assumption, then suppose $(ab)^k=e$, where $k$ is the smallest integer. So $|ab|=k$. Since $G$ is abelian, $(ab)^k=a^k b^k=e$.  Thus, $(a^k)^{-1}=b^k$ and likewise the same goes for, $(b^k)^{-1}=a^k$. Therefore $(b^k)^{-1}\in\langle a\rangle$ and  $(a^k)^{-1}\in\langle b\rangle$. So each of $a^k$ and $b^k$ are the identity. Therefore $k$ is a multiple of $n$ and $m$, so we can say $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)\mid k$. How do I get the last piece I need?

Comment: Just so you know, you don't have to have the condition that $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle$ contains the identity, since both of those are subgroups of $G$, and all subgroups of $G$ must contain $e$ otherwise they don't preserve the 'group' structure. I think you have to assume that $a$ and $b$ have finite order, and that $a$ is not a power of $b$ and vice versa.

Comment: yes I know, but that is how the question starts off.

Comment: Gotcha. Guess the question was written a little strangely, then.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n = \text{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$. So we can write $n = |a|r = |b|s$ for some positive integers $r$ and $s$.

Then $(ab)^{n} = a^{n}b^{n} = (a^{|a|})^{r}(b^{|b|})^{s} = e^{r}e^{s} = e$, so $|ab|$ divides $n$.

On the other hand, your argument above shows that $n$ divides $|ab|$, and so we have equality.

Comment: why does $(ab)^n = 0 $  immediately imply that |ab| divides n ?

Comment: @SamaelManasseh If $(ab)^n = 0$, let $d = \gcd(a,b)$. I claim that $d = |ab|$. To prove this, write $d = |ab|i + nj$ for some integers $i$ and $j$ using the Euclidean algorithm. Then $(ab)^d = (ab)^{|ab|i + nj} = 0$ since $(ab)^{|ab|} = (ab)^n = 0$. Therefore, if $d \neq |ab|$, then $d$ is a smaller positive integer than $|ab|$ such that $(ab)^d = 0$. This contradicts the definition of $|ab|$, hence $d = |ab|$ which implies that $n$ is a multiple of $|ab|$.

Answer (score 0):

($k\neq 0$).

This show that $\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)\leq k$.

$(ab)^{\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)}=e$ , hence $k=\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$ ($k$ is the smallest integer $\neq 0$).

Comment: how is this true? $(ab)^{\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)}=e$

Comment: @Jack $(ab)^r=a^rb^r$

Comment: With the comment of @egreg  , and that   $a^{\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)}=e$ and $b^{\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)}=e$

Comment: but |a|=n and |b|=m. how does the the lcm(|a|,|b|)=k, thats what im trying to prove. I understand your statement egreg, but the answer has no explanation.

Comment: $(ab)^{\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)}=e$ implies that $k\leq \mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$, because $k$ is the smallest with this property. But we have also $ \mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)\le k$, hence $k=\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$.

Comment: I guess Im just not seeing how $(ab)^{lcm(|a|,|b|)}$=e

Comment: $\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$ is a multiple of $|a|$ hence $a^{\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)}=e$,and  $\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$ is a miltiple of $|b|$ hence $b^{\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)}=e$, and $(ab)^{\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)}=a^{\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)}b^{\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)}=ee=e$